# Injective mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, vector-analysis

I have been searching for a proper explanation to **" The Injective Mapping Theorem "** in R. G. Bartle which deals with derivatives of vector functions, but most of the results I found till now gives only definition and properties of Injective mapping of functions

[The Inversion Mapping theorem as in R. G. Bartle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnJuG.png)

1.) Is the name of the concept ( or theorem ) different or is Bartle the only one who deals with it ?

2.)  Can anyone give a good explanation of it I need it in terms of Real Analysis ,cause I haven't done much of topology or other analysis subjects, can you please refer to some sources.

3.) What I understood of it was that if the differential is continuous and injective then the function is also injective in the neighbourhood of the point of differentiation.

( If my understanding is right ) can I also know why it is not injective over the entire domain of f and only in the neighbourhood of the point of differentiation, it would be clear if there is a counter example.

Comment: thank you for looking into it in advance.

Comment: Robert G. Bartle is the well known author of " Introduction to Real Analysis ". My question was is there a simpler alternative proof of the theorem. I would also like to know why only in the neighbourhood the function is injective and not over the entire domain of f.